# Avoid border on middle of 2 divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this situation as you can see in the image:
[image]

And I want to avoid the the border highlighted with red circle using css.
Is this possible, a sample would be great :)

CSS

```
  .home_menu li a {
   padding: 6px 0px 6px 12px;
  }

.home_menu li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-left: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}
.home_menu li .subMenu{
  position: absolute;
  left: 164px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-list home_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Automotiv</a>
                    <div class="subMenu">
                        Test
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Electronic & Technology</a></li>
  ...
 </ul>
```

Comment: You need to also show your current code, what you have tried to solve the problem, and why that was an insufficient solution.

Comment: Here it is the code :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here its a sample I just created http://www.bootply.com/m1w9kzfNfw for this(pure HTML&JS).

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-list home_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Automotiv</a>
                    <div class="subMenu">
                        Test
                    </div>
                    <span class="hidder"></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Electronic &amp; Technology</a>
                    <div class="subMenu">
                        Test
                    </div>
                    <span class="hidder"></span>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

css

```
 .home_menu li a {
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 12px;
}

.home_menu li .subMenu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
 min-height: 100px;
 min-width: 300px;
 padding: 5px;
 z-index: 20;
 border-top-right-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px; 
}
.home_menu li .hidder {
 display: none;
 width: 2px;
 height: 95.5%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 right: -1px;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 100;
}

.home_menu li:hover a {
 background-color: white;
 border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-left: 3px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-top-left-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
.home_menu li a:hover {background-color: #fff}
.home_menu li:hover .hidder{display:inline-block;}
.home_menu li:hover .subMenu{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this solution has all the same essential components that are in my answer, that didn't seem right to you.

Comment: Yes is totally as you said but the problem was I was looking for sample, you just give an idea, how it may be an solution and the reason I answered my question was may my sample & user idea with help others :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish this is to make the "Automotiv" `a` element be positioned above the "Test" div using `z-index`.  Then move it left just far enough that its border will be hidden by the background color of "Automotiv".  Also suppress the right border of "Automotiv" using CSS.

Comment: This is really just guessing.  He would need to actually show his code to know the problem.

Comment: Still, it would be better to ask for clarification or close the question.

Comment: I see, i suppose we should agree to disagree.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but It didn't seems to me the right way of solving it :) however thank you

Answer (score 2):

Move div sub menu a little bit to the left. and make the z-index of the link automotiv 12 or higher to be on top.
And add some css style to the link automotiv that will take off the right border.

Hope this technique will solve tha interface that you want.

Comment: It would be better to ask for clarification to assure that you understand the problem.  Without code, it is effectively guessing.

Comment: It is clear to the description that he want to take off the border between automotiv and div sub menu so it is not guessing. it is how you can understand Properly the problem.

Comment: Its clear enought but let him have the code :D, the automotiv doesn't have border-right but the subMenu has border around, however it have sense.